# Django 2 function calls - 2 different results

Tags: python, django

When I call the first function, there are no errors. When I call the second function, I get the error:
**Field 'id' expected a number but got <Product: Hoodie adidas (Clothes)>**.

How is this possible?

First function:

```
Basket.objects.filter(user=current_user,
                      product=_get_product_by_id(product_id=product_id))
```

Second function:

```
def _is_user_have_product_in_basket_by_id(user: str, 
                                          product_id: any) -> bool:
    return len(Basket.objects.filter(user=user,
                                     product_id=_get_product_by_id(product_id=product_id))) == 0
```

Additional function

```
def _get_product_by_id(product_id: int) -> int:
    return Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
```

Comment: One filters on `product=...`, the other on `product_id=...`. Unsurprisingly the `_id` expects something id-like.

Comment: Btw, why not just: `Basket.objects.filter(user=current_user, product_id=product_id)` Why retrieve the product first in an extra db hit?

Comment: @schwobaseggl theank u! On account of the other answer, I was mistaken, the product itself is gentle in the function call, and not its id

Answer (score 0):

The `product_id` expects an int, not a `Product` object. If you do not need the `Product` itself, but the `Basket`(s), you can filter *without* fetching the `Product` object first:

```
def _is_user_have_product_in_basket_by_id(user: str, product_id: any) -> bool:
    return not Basket.objects.filter(
        user__username=user, product_id=product_id
    ).exists()
```

It is more efficient to work with `product_id` since we then not make a database query to fetch the related object.

Furthermore it is more efficient to work with [**`.exists()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) since this prevents loading all objects in memory.